# Return a Histogram with the table names as categories

Tags: r, histogram

I have a table of probabilities for each number 0:9, the data looks like this:

```
 0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9 
 0.0905 0.1065 0.1035 0.0945 0.0975 0.1025 0.1000 0.0985 0.1010 0.1055
```

If I run a histogram on the data, it groups by probability, when I would like the table grouped by the table name (digit) and then have the bar display the probability. The current histogram looks like this:

[image: plot]

Comment: You seem to confuse a histogram with a bar chart, correct?

Comment: Like Konrad said, sounds like a bar chart. Try: `barplot(table(VARIABLENAME))`

Comment: I believe so. When using the barplot function I get what I need.  However, I have an assignment where the professor states to use the histogram function. Seems silly.  Thanks Konrad.

Comment: Do you really start with the probability table? Because using `hist` might make sense with the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Technically wrong but you can fake a histogram:

```
x <- rbind(c(0.0905, 0.1065, 0.1035, 0.0945, 0.0975, 0.1025, 0.1000, 0.0985, 0.1010, 0.1055))
colnames(x) <- 0:9


barplot(x, space = 0, #sets space between bars to zero as in a histogram
        ylab = "Probabilities" , xaxt='n') #supress labels of x-axis
axis(1, at =  colnames(x), labels = colnames(x)) # add custom axis and labels to look like histogram
box()
```

[image]